# Conversion between types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, type-conversion

This is a question about class design. I am confuse about how the compiler will deal with those two classes.
As a object oriented language C++ need to optimize le layer of abstraction or type abstraction to be efficient. An example that I can think about are iterator. They are a totaly different type than a pointer and yet the compiler can optimise and for example in a for loop be as efficient as a pointer.

What I am concern about is how to make those two classes as efficient if they would be only one. The two classes are the mathematic representation of a Point3 and a Vector3.

Operation on Point3 are really limited but in mathematic we can make a Vector3 out of a Point3 by substracting it from the Origin. we can also do the oposite by considering the end of the Vector3 as a Point3.

An example of this would be to scale a Point3.

```
Point3<float> positionStart;
Vector3<float> scale;
Point3<float> positionEnd;

positionEnd = scale * positionStart;
```

This should convert the `positionStart` Point3 to a Vector3, do the multiplication and then take the end point of the temporary Vector3 to assign it to the `positionEnd`.

How do we code this efficiently in C++ so that those conversion don't actually happen. Because in the end Point3 and Vector3 are represented by 3 floats. At runtime it should mather if it was a Point3 or a Vector3 but compiler should care about the type not the processor.

I hope this is clear I'll try to explain better my confusion if not.

thanks

** Update **
To focus a bit more the question, this can be done with conversion constructors or conversion.  operators. The internal are actually the same. Will the compiler be able to see trough and optimize out, I guess by inlining, those constructors and conversion operators.

Comment: What does it mean to multiply a point by a vector?  I'm not sure that overloading `*` is a good idea here...

Comment: You can overload operators to take different types of 3D objects without having to use any type conversions. But what would the operations actually mean?

Comment: It doesn't mean much, but are mathematic tools. The intermediary operation don't necessarily have mean but the end have. You could want to scale a vertex while generating a 3D box for example.

Comment: @monamimani: It is considered bad practice to use overloaded operators to perform operations that don't have much meaning.

Comment: I would prefer not to use overload of operator because it is not a valid operation for points but it is a valid operation for vectors. Thus a conversion to a vector need to be done. Probably a implicit conversion would be better. Here what I really want is that at the end the compiler optimize out those conversion.

Comment: OK, are you attempting to do an element-wise scaling? If so, you should have use kind of 3D transformation class, rather than a vector. For this particular transformation, its internal representation can be a 3 component entity.

Comment: Yes, it is becoming a bit too specific to the example. Even the trasformation class I would want to code it in term of a Vector3 to reuse code so I would come back to the same design problem.

Comment: No, you just provide a multiplication operator `Point3 operator*(const Scale3D&, const Point3&)`, and similar ones for other types of 3D transformations (rotations, translations, shearing etc.) This makes the intent clear.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to have the point coordinates be stored internally as a vector. Since I have no idea what `operator*` would do, I'll show it with `operator+` where the sematics is clear (note however that this is untested code):

```
template<typename Field> class Point
{
public:
  Point& operator+=(Vector<Field> const& v);
  // the rest of the Point interface
private:
  Vector<Field> position; // holds the vector from the origin to this point
};

template<typename Field>
 inline Point<Field>::operator+=(Vector<Field> const& v)
{
  position += v;
}

template<typename Field>
 inline Point<Field> operator+(Point<Field> p, Vector<Field> const& v)
{
  return p += v;
}
```

Now, `p += v` will be optimized to the exact code that `p.position += v` would compile to if `position` were not private. So ultimately you have only a vector addition.

Comment: But i don't want an Point3 operator*(Point3 p, Vector3 const& v). What I want is Vector3 operator*(Vector3 lhs, const Vector3& rhs), but count on the conversion operator, operator Vector3() const font the Point3 class to convert the rhs from Point3 to Vector3 and then for the assignment to count on the constructor of Point3, Point3(const Vector3& vec). What I hope is that the conversion operator and constructor will get optimize out. Is it too much to ask to the compiler?

Comment: @monamimani: *Why* do you not want that operator? If you do implicit conversions between `Point` and `Vector` anyway, then what is the point (no pun intended) of having the `Point` class instead of just working with `Vector`s exclusively?

Comment: @monamimani you seem to be worried about the efficiency of type conversions, when there is no need for these conversions.